# Would a shake-to-scroll-to-the-top scroll view annoy users?

Tags: buttons, scrolling, gestures

I have a very functional and minimal application where I try to maintain functionality and screen real estate at the same time.

My scroll view takes up the whole screen and I would like it to stay that way. Jamming a button onto the scroll view to scroll to top is my last resort.

I would like to implement a shake gesture to scroll to the top. Would users be annoyed with such a gesture? Any idea what else I could do? (maybe a suggestion for a gesture?)

Comment: Hi @Martin.  Welcome to the site!  You may want to have a look at the answers to [Is shaking a device to refresh an accepted behavior?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38683/is-shaking-a-device-to-refresh-an-accepted-behavior) and see if those answer your question.

Comment: Opera's strategy to resolve the real estate problem is to have a top bar.  When you first load a page, it is visible.  If you scroll down, it is hidden (because it scrolls out of the page).  If you scroll up, it scrolls into view (i.e., when scrolling down, the top bar follows you, just above the viewport).  As for scroll-to-top and scroll-to-bottom, Opera's strategy is to have giant buttons on the right side of the screen for each direction...but the buttons only become visible if the user is scrolling up or down at high speed.

Comment: @Brian Yeah apps like Pinterest use that I think... But I do not plan to have a bar at all. A gesture works fine by me :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes.**

Not because I think it's a big problem (I know other think it's bad though),
but because I often pick up my phone and find it **unintentionally shaken**.

The Google+ app brings up the bug-report form when shaken, and standard iOS behavior is to "undo".  When I pick up my phone and find the messages "send bug?" or "really undo?" and I always think: "Oh, I'm glad they want me to confirm this action"...

(And when I intentionally want to "undo" something, I alway look over my shoulder to see if anyone observes my phone-shaking :-P)

Comment: Yeah thank you for your answer Jørn. I found myself hating it over the course of the development stage, so I guess I am going to go with a right swipe. It works well and is easily accessible.

Comment: Is there a built-in gesture to return to the top of the screen in Google apps? In iOS, pressing the top edge of the screen returns users to the top of a Safari window. If there is, you may want to consider adopting that.

Comment: I find the same in iOS when I unintentionally shake during typing and get the "Undo typing" alert view. Happens a lot.